# Regarding serializing the array list object

Tags: java

I have an array list that I want to serialize please advise how to I will be able to do that..

```
 ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
      list.add("Ram");
      list.add("Sachin");
      list.add("Dinesh");
      list.add(1,"Ravi");
      list.add("Dinesh");
      list.add("Anupam");
      System.out.println("There are "+list.size()+" elements in the list.");
      System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
      Iterator itr=list.iterator();
      while(itr.hasNext())
      System.out.println(itr.next());
     }
```

}

I want to use the serialization mechanism so that I can save it in file

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more information fo rus to be able to help you. Do you really mean "serialize" as in `java.io.Serializable`? Because if so, `ArrayList` **is** serializable, so you'd just open an `ObjectOutputStream` and write the `ArrayList` to it. But I assume there must be more to it than that.

Comment: serialize to what? XML? json? binary?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. Both `ArrayList` and `String` (that you store in the list) implement `Serializable` interface, so you can use the standard java mechanism for serialization:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile"));
oos.writeObject(list);
............
oos.fluch();
oos.close();
```

In this example I wrapped FileOutputStream with ObjectOutputStream but obviously you can use any other payload stream.

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code, that will be a gresat help

Comment: minor typo up there should be `flush` rather than `fluch`, methinks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own methods for serializing and deserializing objects. The below are useful methods for doing just that.

```
public static Object deserializeBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    ByteArrayInputStream bytesIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bytesIn);
    Object obj = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return obj;
}


public static byte[] serializeObject(Object obj) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOut);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.flush();
    byte[] bytes = bytesOut.toByteArray();
    bytesOut.close();
    oos.close();
    return bytes;
}
```